# Django elasticsearch unable to import modules

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am new to python and have some experience with Elasticsearch. I am trying to index my Model from Django to Elasticsearch. I have configured `django-elasticsearch-dsl` as per the official website. However, when I runserver, I got

```
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk, parallel_bulk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch.helpers'
```

This happens only with my project which I worked for almost 2 weeks and have many models and data in it. I tried to create a new project and used `django-elasticsearch-dsl` where I could connect to elasticsearch without any issues.

I am not sure how to resolve this in my existing `project/venv`.

Comment: You probably need to install this module to your venv. Activate your venv, then install the package using pip. It should solve your problem.

Comment: I am using PyCharm and all the modules required for this project is installed in venv. Also as mentioned when I create a new project and install the module in the venv it works fine.

Comment: What is the diff between pip freeze of your two venv?

Comment: There is no difference in pip freeze between both of my venv. I ended up creating a new project, apps and then copied all mode code to the new project. Now i am able to use the module and connect to elasticsearch . Thanks all